# How to count records with averages in range

Tags: sql, count, average

I need to count number of students with average grade from 7.6 to 8.3
I tried

```
Select count(*) from tabele
Where AVG(grade)> 7.6
and AVG(Grade)<8.3 
Group by id
```

But there is always an error

Comment: You have to get the averages *first*, then you can count them.  You can't do them at the same time/level.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach below is to first aggregate by student `id` and assert the average grade requirements in a `HAVING` clause.  Then, subquery to find the count of such matching students.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING AVG(Grade) > 7.6 AND AVG(Grade) < 8.3
) t;
```

Assuming your RDBMS support window functions, here is one way we can get the count with a single query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING AVG(Grade) > 7.6 AND AVG(Grade) < 8.3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use having clause here instead of where. Also sum(count(distinct id)) could be used to count the number of values. Alternatively you could use a subquery to achieve the same result.

```
select sum(count(distinct id)) from table_name
group by id
having AVG(grade) BETWEEN  7.6 and 8.3;
```

Comment: 1) HAVING comes _after_ GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh true. In oracle it shouldn't matter, but the person who asked could indeed use a different dbms.

Comment: amazing, never heard of this before!

Answer (score 0):

Somehting like this should work

```
    WITH _CTE AS 
(
    SELECT StudentId, AVG(Grade) as avgGrade
    FROM MyTalbe
    GROUP BY StudentId
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM _CTE
WHERE avgGrade > 7.6
AND avgGrade < 8.3
```